# Complex conditional filtering of dataset

Tags: r, filtering

I have a dataset of interactions where many are psuedo-replicates that I need to filter out. I need identify (and then remove) all instances where the same interaction occurs with the same individual within a certain time window (say 10 secs), but only as long as these interactions are consecutive (they are not repeats if another interaction occurs between them).

My data looks is laid out like so:

```
  Datetime      Interaction   Individual 
1 190513064553  DUAL_SUCCESS  01151e00
2 190513064605  SOLO_SUCCESS  078c6700
3 190513064609  SOLO_SUCCESS  01151e00
4 190513064613  SOLO_SUCCESS  078c6700
5 190513071534  SOLO_SUCCESS  078c6700   
6 190513071541  SOLO_SUCCESS  078c6700
```

So in this example, if the window was 10 seconds, the process would filter out line 6, but not lines 3 or 4, as although line 4 appears a replicate of 2 and is within 10 seconds, it is split by a different individual.

I realise this is a niche situation, but any advice would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: One cannot just paste this data to R. Please, provide a reproducible example for greater convenience

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slightly shorter version of your dataset:

```
Datetime<- c(190513064553,  190513064605, 190513064609, 190513064633)
Interaction <- c("DUAL_SUCCESS", "SOLO_SUCCESS", "SOLO_SUCCESS", "SOLO_SUCCESS")
Individual <- c (1,2,3,3)
df <- data.frame(Datetime, Interaction, Individual)
```

Step 1: Creating additional columns:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(time_window = Datetime - lag(Datetime),
         same_int = (Interaction == lag(Interaction)),
         same_ind = (Individual == lag(Individual)))

      Datetime  Interaction Individual time_window same_int same_ind
1 190513064553 DUAL_SUCCESS          1          NA       NA       NA
2 190513064605 SOLO_SUCCESS          2          52    FALSE    FALSE
3 190513064609 SOLO_SUCCESS          3           4     TRUE    FALSE
4 190513064633 SOLO_SUCCESS          3          24     TRUE     TRUE
```

Step 2: Filtering dataset by the new columns

```
df %>% 
  mutate(time_window = Datetime - lag(Datetime),
         same_int = (Interaction == lag(Interaction)),
         same_ind = (Individual == lag(Individual))) %>%
  filter(!(time_window > 10 & !is.na(time_window) & same_int & same_ind))

      Datetime  Interaction Individual time_window same_int same_ind
1 190513064553 DUAL_SUCCESS          1          NA       NA       NA
2 190513064605 SOLO_SUCCESS          2          52    FALSE    FALSE
3 190513064609 SOLO_SUCCESS          3           4     TRUE    FALSE
```

If necessary, the newly created columns can be now removed by adding `%>% select(-c(time_window, same_int, same_ind))`